# .net database for local and website - Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio-2013

tl;dr:

What is a database that is easy to implement in VSE13 and will not require my end users to install extra software for the database?

See the screenshots below.

---

I wasn't able to come up with a good way to explain this, so...

I'm recreating a program that is no longer available (except on free-sites) and is not updated. ("Anime List Builder" if your interested in seeing what I'm trying to do here).
My program is visually similar to the images below, and (hopefully) will work like it does:

[Screenshot 1](http://www.DSoSWeb.com/Images/AnimeListBuilder/Anime-List-Builder_2.png)

[Screenshot 2](http://www.DSoSWeb.com/Images/AnimeListBuilder/Anime-List-Builder_3.png)

I've read MSDN, searched google and SO and couple of other sites. The more I read on databases, the more confused on which database would be the best for this type of program, while keeping it simple for the end user with no extra software needed.

For this type of program, what would you suggest for a database? Keep in mind this will be a free download, and not everyone has access to Access or SQL, etc. also, the user will be able to export the data to html and XML for the online database.

Thank You the time and any help offered :)

---

Extra Info:

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 (for Windows Desktop)

Exporting to html is optional. I'm not worrying about trying to export the database to XML yet, so lets not bring this in, although I did.

When I used the original program (Anime List Builder) I had 200+ entries, each entry can have 100's of extra files attached, each with File Size, (optional past this)  CRC, SAH1 md5, a display image, screenshots, comments, and more.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question will result in primarily opinion based results which is against the StackOverflow core principles.

Comment: I didn't think about it being an opinion based result. Thank You for the tip and the answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your requirement there are various database systems that will work without actually installing any third party software.

Based on the fact that this is a single user application (as it appears) you would probably be best using a database called [SqlLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) which is basically a file based embedded database. Now there are [.Net wrappers](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) already available for this database type and they are very easy to use.

Additionally there is a [SqlLite.Net ORM](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) system available to speed up your development.

As I did say there are some other file based solutions.

- [SQL CE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=17876)
- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html)

Anyway, as I posted in the comment this is primarily opinion based and may be closed. Here is another thread on SO that discusses the same concepts.

[What is a good embedded database to use with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c)

Comment: Thank You for the answer and I will look into the solutions you gave. As you stated, this is opinion based, and maybe be closed now.